# DXA 1.7 install on SDL Web 8.5 - DiscoveryEndpointUrl must be unique

Tags: web8, dxa

Yet more problems following the [the single-machine installation for 8.5](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-838FECB4-383C-4FA2-858C-8DD93AB39C83&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-838FECB4-383C-4FA2-858C-8DD93AB39C83.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-838FECB4-383C-4FA2-858C-8DD93AB39C83) - did anyone actually test these instructions, I might start a blog series on getting through it!

I'm on the **Installing SDL Digital Experience Accelerator for the sample single-machine installation** part, running `ttm-prepare.ps1`.

The guide says:

> When it asks for a DXA staging Web site base URL, enter visitorsweb

If you do that it complains about the string not being a well-formed URL.

As a guess, I put in http://localhost:82. I then get:

> The base URL "http://localhost:82" is already used as a base URL in
>   another website with Id 'visitorsweb'.

Sigh.

For the hell of it, I put http://localhost. Initially I'm asked about OAuth credentials that I put in based on what the guide tells me, no errors, yipee!
I'm asked to provide info for Live.

But if I use the same Discovery URL I get:

> Property 'DiscoveryEndpointUrl' of the item of type
>   'CdEnvironmentData' must be unqie. Source of conflict 'SampleCD'.

Sigh.

I'm assuming that because the guide had me only create one CD environment thats why I get this message?

Comment: I know for a fact the technical writer who wrote that guide, did actually execute all the steps in that guide before writing them down. I'll alert him on your question here, and see if he has a response/solution for you.

Comment: More problems when running cmd-import.ps1. I think there's an assumption my CMS is running under http://localhost/visitorweb - which it is not. But even when I give the correct, default URL of http://localhost:81 I get an error about the Core Service could not be activated. Sigh.

Comment: I share your pain Neil... I wrote this one hoping to help others: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install/

Comment: Nice - Ill probably go that way next time, but I'm persevering to try get the maximum benefit. To be fair, the Core Service problem seems to be memory related - I just noticed the VM I have is only running 4GB of RAM so Ill need to up that.

Comment: Good luck. All-in-one machines seem to need 12 GB to run smoothly, and for CM alone I tend to use 8.

Comment: Indeed, the current (DXA) installation instruction in SDL Web 8.5 docs seems broken in every possible way! Which is quite remarkable, because we indeed recently invested in documenting a detailed, tested, procedure. I have been told that this problem will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the exact same problem for a few weeks, but it seems that the [documentation has updated](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-838FECB4-383C-4FA2-858C-8DD93AB39C83) in the last few days. I had to roll back all of my install, but using the new method I have taken my installation further. I am still running into problems on the last step, fixed by downloading a new copy of DXA. I hope this helps!

Comment: The documentation has been fixed yes, since last Friday the guide should be correct and working for SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 1.7 http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88